# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un select en php y msql?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas hace poco que estoy incursionando en php y no sé como poner una consulta de mysql dentro del código, tengo este select en php que me trae todos los valores de la tabla y quisiera que me traiga sólo del query que está más abajo.Le agradezco mucho por su ayuda!

```
       <!-- Esta es la fracción de php-->
<select name="ecategory" class="form-control">
       <?php while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($expense)){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $col['CategoryId'];?>">
       <?php echo $col['CategoryName'];?></option>
                                        <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

pero me gustaría que filtre esta consulta

```
select distinct category.CategoryId, category.CategoryName
 from category
 where tipo = 10
```

Comment: ¿Donde tienes la consulta a la bd de mysqli?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, lo que no te da es la consulta o que?

Comment: Simplemente crea ese select en php tal cual, si tipo depende de una variable concatena al `SELECT` esa variable, de forma que se asemeje a sql. De hecho si has sido capaz de hacer un `SELECT` de toda la tabla, es exactamente lo mismo solo añadiendo la clausula `WHERE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mostrar los resultados que necesitas deberías hacer algo así:

```
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");
$query = "select distinct category.CategoryId, category.CategoryName from category where tipo = 10";
$query2 = "select distinct category.CategoryId, category.CategoryName from category where tipo = 5";
$mResult = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
$mResult2 = mysqli_query($conexion,$query2);
?>
<select name="ecategory" class="form-control">
       <?php while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mResult )){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $col['CategoryId'];?>">
       <?php echo $col['CategoryName'];?></option>
                                        <?php } ?>
 </select>
 <select name="ecategory2" class="form-control">
       <?php while($col2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mResult2 )){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $col2['CategoryId'];?>">
       <?php echo $col2['CategoryName'];?></option>
                                        <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder Lucas, ahora te consulto como podría incluir otro select, además de ese, de otra consulta? es decir que haya dos select de dos consultas. Sería algo como lo que puse abajo.

Comment: @ManuAbella te acabo de responder editando la pregunta

Comment: Gracias eres un capo! @Luccas D.A.W.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", 
"mi_bd");
$query = "select distinct category.CategoryId, category.CategoryName from 
category where tipo = 10";
$query = "select distinct category.CategoryId, category.CategoryName from 
category where tipo = 11";

$mResult = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
?>
  <select name="ecategory" class="form-control">
   <?php while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mResult )){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $col['CategoryId'];?>">
   <?php echo $col['CategoryName'];?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
  </select>
  <select name="ecategory" class="form-control">
   <?php while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mResult )){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $col['CategoryId'];?>">
   <?php echo $col['CategoryName'];?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
     </select>
```